How to configure the SmallRye Fault Tolerance annotation values at the runtime in the application.yml file such as maxRetries for @Retry?
I am using the Quarkus SmallRye Fault Tolerance annotation such as @Retry within my Quarkus application. I have many methods with Retry logic for which I want to use the SmallRye Fault Tolerance so I changed old code from:
.onFailure()
.retry()
.withBackOff(200)
.withJitter(200)
.atMost(5)
.onFailure()
.recoverWithUni(throwable -> Uni.createFrom().item("failed"));

To this new code with @Retry (The method is a public method with a class annotated with @ApplicationScoped):
@Retry(maxRetries = 5, delay = 200, jitter = 200)
@Fallback(fallbackMethod = "handleFailure")

The above annotations work fine on the failure and can run 5+1 six times during the failure and finally return the default value onFailure from the handleFailure method.
Since I have many methods and classes in my application I don't want to define the values for maxRetries, delay, jitter on each of them rather I want to define them within application.yml properties file.
In future, if I want to change any information I can change it from the properties file and on methods just define the annotation @Retry so the rest of the information will be picked up during the run-time from the application.yml properties file.
Based on the documentation I tried the following:
application.yml file:
Retry/maxRetries=5
Retry/delay=200
Retry/jitter=200

But this does not seem to work at all for me. It's for some reason using the default values, not the ones I provided in my config.
Is it possible to configure the values for SmallRye Fault Tolerance in the application.yml file? I did not find any concrete example anywhere in the documentation or on GitHub. Can someone help me with this issue? What is the right way to define the run-time configuration for SmallRye Fault Tolerance? Please provide a complete YML tree so I can see these values should go under which parent
quarkus:
  # ... other existing configurations ...

  smallrye-fault-tolerance:
    retry:
      max-retries: 5


Update on 25.10 based on a comment from @Ladicek :
I tried to create a simple Quarkus app with SmallRye Fault Tolerance with application.properties and it worked pretty fine with @Retry when making the API calls:
quarkus.http.port=8081
Retry/maxRetries=8
Retry/delay=2
Retry/delayUnit=SECONDS

Following is my CakeResource.java:
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.faulttolerance.Fallback;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.faulttolerance.Retry;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import java.util.Random;


@Path("/api/bake")
@ApplicationScoped
public class CakeResource {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CakeResource.class);
    private final Random r = new Random();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Retry()
    @Fallback(fallbackMethod = "defaultFallback")
    public String bakeCake() throws Exception {
        logger.info("****** Newly Backing Cake ********");
        final Double randDouble = r.nextDouble();
        logger.info(randDouble);

        if (randDouble < 0.5) {
            logger.info(" No items left sorry .... ");
            throw new Exception();
        }

        if (randDouble < 0.999) {
            logger.info(" oops Cake burned... ");
            throw new Exception();
        }

        logger.info(" Cake prepared ");

        return "Here is your take, Guten Appetit\n";
    }

    public String defaultFallback() {
        return "Sorry unable prepare the cake today \n";
    }
}

Now for the same above CakeResource, I used the application.yml instead of application.properties. I added quarkus-config-yaml to the pom.xml file and changed application.yml to this:
quarkus:
  http:
    port: 8081

Retry:
  maxRetries: 5
  delay: 2
  delayUnit: SECONDS

The @Retry config in application.yml was ignored, defaulting to maxRetries: 3 and delay: 0. Other settings, like port, were applied, so application.yml was recognized, but not for SmallRye Fault Tolerance configs.
I also tried the following:
Approach-1 :
quarkus:
  http:
    port: 8082

smallrye-fault-tolerance:
  retry:
    max-retries: 5
    delay: PT2S

Approach-2 :
quarkus:
  http:
    port: 8083

mp:
  fault-tolerance:
    retry:
      max-retries: 3 
      delay: 500     
      jitter: 100    

Approach-3 :
quarkus:
  http:
    port: 8081

  smallrye-fault-tolerance:
    retry:
      max-retries: 5
      delay: PT2S
      jitter: PT0.2S

Approach-4:
quarkus:
  http:
    port: 8081

mp:
  fault-tolerance:
    retry:
      max-retries: 5
      delay: PT2S
      jitter: PT0.2S

smallrye-fault-tolerance:
  retry:
    max-retries: 5
    delay: PT2S
    jitter: PT0.2S

None of the configurations worked for me in application.yml. I'm unsure if it's a setup issue or if SmallRye Fault Tolerance doesn’t read properties from application.yml. Can you confirm how to use runtime configurations with SmallRye Fault Tolerance via application.yml?

This absolutely should work. Did you try using application.properties instead of application.yml? If that works, then perhaps there's an issue in the YAML config source.

@Ladicek Thanks a lot for the response. I did not try using the application.properties as my complete application runs using the application.yml file I was testing in that.

Could you please test that, then? We need to figure out if that is the problem, or if the problem is elsewhere.

@Ladicek Thanks a lot again and based on your suggestion I tried the approach. Seems like application.properties works fine but when using the application.yml it does not work or I am setting them wrong. I have provided the Resource example and the config file. Can you please once check and let me know if I am doing something wrong. I have added all the things I have tried and code blocks in the above question itself.

@BATMAN_2008 please add also the application.properties version too so that it would be easy to compare them and maybe spot some useful differences

As mentioned in https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-fault-tolerance/issues/1068, the SmallRye Fault Tolerance extension for Quarkus does not (yet) support a natively looking configuration. We have to use the MP FT config keys without alteration. That is, Retry/maxRetries must not be split into separate lines in the YAML format.

@Ladicek Thanks a lot for providing the suggestion. Its working for me now.

Based on the response provided by @Ladicek:
There is no support for natively looking Quarkus configuration, so we have to use the raw MicroProfile Fault Tolerance config keys.
quarkus:
  http:
    port: 8081

Retry/maxRetries: 8
Retry/delay: 2
Retry/delayUnit: SECONDS

